# What's the best way to hang these pictures?

Tags: geometry

I am hanging some pictures in my house. Four pictures are the same size (17 in x 23 in). These pictures are already hung in a straight line with about 7.5 inches between such that the entire line measures 106 inches, crudely represented below:

```
[x] [x] [x] [x]
<-----106----->
```

I want to hang two more pictures:
bigger picture measures 32.5 x 18 and smaller is 23 x 18.5. (Longest dimension is horizontal, unit is inches.)

At this point I'm opting to hang them based on the total horizontal distance they take up. Bigger takes up 58.5% and smaller is 43.9%. (Because 32.5/(32.5 + 23) = 58.5%.) So I'm going to set 58.5% * 106 inches = 62.1 inches from the edge as the equidistant point as follows:

```
   [  Big  ]<>|<>[ sm ]     (Where "<>" is a set, equal distance.)
<----63.1---->|
[ x ]  [ x ]  [ x ]  [ x ]
<-----------106---------->
```

Can anyone think of another/better way to position the pictures?

Comment: This is actually a pretty cool question.

Comment: Thanks :) hoping for some insightful answers!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an opinion-based question and is susceptible to deletion by purists, but...

A harmonious division of space is always achieved by dividing it according to the Golden Ratio, so try dividing the full length of $106$ in the ratio $1.618:1$ and set the larger picture at the midpoint of the larger space, and the smaller picture likewise in the smaller space.